# @JsonSerialize and @JsonDeserialize not working when included in an annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, serialization

I am trying to create a custom annotation to tokenize a given property always when it is annotated with, so I have the following structure:

```
@JsonComponent
public class TokenSerializer {

    @JsonSerialize(using = IdToTokenSerializer.class) // This does not work 
    @JsonDeserialize(using = TokenToIdDeserializer.class) // This does not work 
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface TokenizedId {
        Class<?> value();
    }

    public static class IdToTokenSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Long> implements ContextualSerializer {
        ...
    }

    public static class TokenToIdDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Long> implements ContextualDeserializer {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Why am I using like that?** Because the `@TokenizedId` will provide a class, which conditionally will be considered on the serializer/deserializer to do something. This value is configured using the `ContextualDeserializer`, fetching the class from `@TokenizedId`.

The issue is, both serializer and deserializer do not work when I annotate just like this:

```
@TokenizedId(MyClass.class)
private Long id;
```

But they work when I use like this (removing the `@JsonSerialize` and `@JsonDeserialize` from `@TokenizedId`):

```
@JsonSerialize(using = IdToTokenSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = TokenToIdDeserializer.class)
@TokenizedId(MyClass.class)
private Long id;
```

Personally I did not like this approach, since developers will need to always remember to use these three annotations when they would like to tokenize some id, and also I would like the `@TokenizedId` always be related to these serializers.

Is there a way to make the serializer/deserializer work when annotated on another annotation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to make the annotation works the way I wanted, looking after some clue on the Jackson lib, I found the `@JacksonAnnotationsInside` annotation:

```
/**
 * Meta-annotation (annotations used on other annotations)
 * used for indicating that instead of using target annotation
 * (annotation annotated with this annotation),
 * Jackson should use meta-annotations it has.
 * This can be useful in creating "combo-annotations" by having
 * a container annotation, which needs to be annotated with this
 * annotation as well as all annotations it 'contains'.
 * 
 * @since 2.0
 */
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotation
public @interface JacksonAnnotationsInside
{

}
```

Including this on my annotation solved the issue:

```
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonSerialize(using = IdToTokenSerializer.class) 
@JsonDeserialize(using = TokenToIdDeserializer.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public static @interface TokenizedId {
    Class<?> value();
}
```