# Custom annotation for @JsonSerialize not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to simplify my code by grouping some annotations in a new custom annotation. This seems to work for other annotations except for @JsonSerialize. If I put this annotation on the class directly it works, when used from another annotation it fails. Why is this happening?

```
@JsonSerialize(using = SecuritySerializer.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface EnableSecurity {
    @AliasFor(
        annotation = JsonSerialize.class,
        attribute = "using"
    )
    Class<? extends JsonSerializer> using() default SecuritySerializer.class;
}
```

This is not working on any class. Do I need the @JsonSerialize annotation on every class?

I am running this on Java 11, spring boot 2.4.0, with jackson-databind 2.11.3

Answer (score 1):

I was missing @JacksonAnnotationsInside annotation. Using this solved my issues.

Working code:

```
@Permission
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonSerialize(using = SecuritySerializer.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@JacksonAnnotation
public @interface EnableSecurity {
    @AliasFor(
         annotation = JsonSerialize.class,
         attribute = "using"
    )
    Class<? extends JsonSerializer> using() default SecuritySerializer.class;
}
```

With thanks to [nullptr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56857059/4664543)